# Rendering database data to browser in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I am having difficulties with showing database data in browser with Django.
I have, for show my issue, just one date in my database.
When I go to the Django Shell I got this:

```
>>>from events.models import Event
>>>Event.objects.all()
<QuerySet [SuperBowl22]
```

My models.py has:

```
from unicodedata import name
from django.db import models
from django.forms import DateTimeField

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name´s event', max_length=120)
    timeEvent = models.DateTimeField ('Event´s date')
    seat_position = models.ForeignKey(Seat_position, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fanatic = models.OneToOneField(EPS, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

My views.py has:

```
from .models import Event
from token import RIGHTSHIFTEQUAL
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from datetime import date

def all_events(request):
    event_list = Event.objects.all()
    return render(request,
        'events/event_list.html',
        {'event_list': event_list}
    )
```

My event_list.HTML has:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Showing database info{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Result(s) of database consultation:</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for events in event_list %}
        <li>{{ event.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    
{% endblock content %}
```

I run the runserver with no errors and go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/events/
and the browser shows:

```
Result(s) of database consultation:

.
```

- Why the HTML is not showing <QuerySet [SuperBowl22] or it equivalent?
- Have I some typo or any small mistake?
- The django shell shows a correct result of the Event.objects.all(). Why there is no result in the web page?

Comment: `{% for events in event_list %}` should be `{% for event in event_list %}` (so `event`, not `events`).

Comment: You are right, thats a mistake...but unfortunately the HTML is still doesnt showing the query

Comment: is it `name` or `nobre` (in the `__str__` it is written as `nombre`...)

Comment: Ohhh myyy! You rocks! Actually my project has "nombre" in models (__str__) but my HTML has "name". I changed this last to "nombre" and thats it!